# Subset sum problem with a complication

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming, arrays

I have a sorted list of numbers. I know they can be divided into two parts. I also know the sum of those 2 parts. I want to know what these subsets are. How can i find them?
The size of my list can be ~ 10^6. The sum of my subsets can be ~ 10^24.
Is there a better way to find my subset with a time complexity of O(n*sum) or O(2^n *n) or is it not possible?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Do you mean that you know that your original list can be partitioned into two lists $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that the sums over their elements are $s_1$ and $s_2$ respectively?

Comment: yes. exactly that.

Comment: You may want to be explicit about the "base way" to find a valid partition to compare other approaches to. What did you try, where did that get you?

Comment: dp soln gives n*sum complexity, recursive/bitmasking gives 2^n

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that your problem seems like inspired from [this](https://www.codechef.com/SEPT20A/problems/EQDIV)  problem which belongs to a running competition?

Comment: @VimalPatel yes it is exactly in reference to that, and if not you, i know that it wont be done using this method. So there's no point in acting like that.

Comment: @VimalPatel also, you'd really like my approach if you've read the question, it wont be done by that, but i found the approach very fascinating

Answer (score 1):

You are fully in the range of numbers where NP-completeness hits you. If you're lucky dynamic programming can be a bit faster, but not much.

Sort the numbers in ascending order. If you take the first k numbers, there are $2^k$ subsets. With dynamic programming, you determine all possible sums, and they will be less than $k \cdot 10^{18}$. Maybe around k = 100 you will hopefully have large ranges of consecutive integers that are possible sums. Let's say all integers from 1,013,460 to 1,576,390 are possible sums, and the next number is $x_{k+1}$. Then all integers in the range 1,013,460 to 1,576,390 are possible sums for k+1 integers, and so are all the integers in $1,013,460+x_{k+1}$ to $1,576,390+x_{k+1}$. Determined in constant time. So with a bit of luck, adding the next k to your DP table can be very little work. Still, the numbers that you have will make this close to impossible.

The best case is some slowly growing numbers. For example, splitting the first billion cubes into two sets with same sum (if the total sum is even) or almost equal sum (if the total sum is odd) should be not very difficult. Or for example n integers randomly picked, but each close to $k^3$.